# Changing ZIndex for Dynamic Card Flatlist which uses Animated API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, z-index, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

I have a flatlist with two columns which renders card components. Once a user clicks a card, it pops up by using Animated API of React Native.

I am changing the clicked component's ZIndex value to 10. When it is closed, the value is set to 0.

The problem is that this logic works only in row elements, but not between rows. So, every other card positioned in a lower indexed row, stays behind the others.

What should I do for this problem? Thank you in advance.

Here is the example;

[image]